# How to export an Influxdb database which is in a docker container?

Tags: database, docker, influxdb

I want to export my influxdb database as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779472/export-data-from-influxdb), but my InfluxDB is in a docker container, and I'm still a beginner with it. How can I execute the following command into my container ? `influxdb backup -database name /opt/data`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a `docker exec` & `docker cp` to backup your data in case you have not used host mounts -

```
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID bash -c "influxdb backup -database name /opt/data"
```

Once your data is generated in /opt/data, copy it to the current directory on Docker host -

```
docker cp $CONTAINER_ID:/opt/data ./
```

Comment: The proper tool name is 'influxd' not 'influxdb'. Also it is recommended to use the new format by specifying -portable. See https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/backup_and_restore/