# How to import InfluxDB tables into QuestDB?

Tags: influxdb, questdb

I am trying to move data from InfluxDB to QuestDB,

I was able to export my tables as JSON by following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913640/1267728

How do I now import these JSON files into QuestDB?

Answer (score 2):

**Convert from JSON  to CSV**

QuestDB supports importing data via CSV file, so first you would need to flatten the JSON and ensure that column names are modified to reflect nested properties.

There is a Java library called [Json2Flat](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat) that already does this.

**Import the CSV file**

Using the REST API, you can import the data into QuestDB

```
curl -F data=file.csv http://localhost:9000/imp
```

For more details of how to use the REST API, please go to the official [documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest/).

**Check the data**

To verify that the import is successful, you can check via the Web Console or via CURL…

```
curl -G --data-urlencode "query=select * from 'file.csv'" http://localhost:9000/exp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding here that QuestDB recently improved the performance of CSV ingestion. More info at https://questdb.io/docs/guides/importing-data/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid converting from JSON (and probably more performant as well than exporting to JSON for large tables), you can use the `influxd inspect export-lp` command that exports all your data as ILP points. You can choose to export a single bucket.

Once you have the ILP files, you can import as explained at this other StackOverflow post [What's the best way to upload an ILP file into QuestDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249217/whats-the-best-way-to-upload-an-ilp-file-into-questdb)