# How to import InfluxDB data into TDengine database?

Tags: influxdb, tdengine

I am handling a lot of time-series data. We have history data stored in InfluxDB.

I can export the data from InfluxDB according to [Export data from InfluxDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779472/export-data-from-influxdb/27913640#27913640).

Then how do I import them to TDengine database?

Answer (score -1):

ETL tools such as DataX with Influxdb reader and TDengine writer plugins may help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).